# All saddles in the unit ball have area $<2\pi$?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

Let $M$ be the *saddle surface* in $\mathbb R^3$ defined by $x^2-y^2+z=0$. For any $r\geq 0$ and $(x_0,y_0,z_0)\in\mathbb R^3$, let $rM+(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ denotes the surface obtained by scaling $M$ by $r$ and then *translating* by $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$. (Note that by $rM$, with $r=0$, we mean $\lim_{r\to 0} rM$, which is two perpendicularly intersecting plane.)  And let $B$ be the unit ball.

Is it true that

***$$\mathrm{area}\left[(rM+(x_0,y_0,z_0))\cap B\right]\leq 2\pi,$$***
with equality holds ***if and only if***  $r=0$ and $(x_0,y_0,z_0)=(0,0,0)$ (which gives two intersecting equatorial disks)?

**Edit:** Using the first variation formula, I can show some partial results:

- For any fixed $z_0$, the area of $(r(M+(0,0,z_0)))\cap B$ decreases as $r$ increases, for all $r\in(0,+\infty)$.
- $(r,x_0,y_0,z_0)=(0,0,0,0)$ is a strict local maximum.

Comment: a numerical evaluation leaves little doubt that this is true...

Comment: Using the first variation formula, I can show that for any fixed
$z_0$, the area of $r(M-(0,0,z_0))$ decreases as $r$ increases from 0.

Comment: @AdCh You mean "decreases on the entire interval $r\in (0,+\infty)$", or just in the neighborhood of $0$?

Comment: @fedja, I meant for all $r>0$. On the other hand, I also managed to show $(r,x_0,y_0,z_0)=(0,0,0,0)$ is a strict local maximum. (I just added this to the post)

Comment: I must be missing something, but to me $rM$ for $r=0$ would consist of a single point (the origin) which would not intersect the unit ball at all...

Comment: @Sam Hopkins
  Ah, $rM$ **tends to** two planes as $r\to 0$.

Comment: @AdCh For $r=0$ you can use any $z_0$, not only $0$, so your "if and only if" statement seems slightly inaccurate. Am I missing anything?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker "a numerical evaluation leaves little doubt that this is true" I'm rather curious how you set up the area integral here and what technique you use for 2D numerical integration. My initial inclination was also to write a computer program but I gave up after I realized how complicated the intersection with the ball can possibly be and how many scenarios I'll have to teach the machine to distinguish between :-(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is actually next to trivial if you choose the right parameterization (and rather puzzling if you don't, so it can make a decent take-home exam problem in multivariate calculus).

I'll use the line cover $x(s,t)=(s+t,s-t,4st)$. The area element is then
$2\sqrt{1+8s^2+8t^2}\,ds\,dt< 2(\sqrt{1+8s^2}+\sqrt{1+8t^2})\,ds\,dt$.

Now for a ball $B$ of radius $R$ centered at $(u,v,w)$ and for fixed $s$, we have the line in $t$ whose moving speed is $\sqrt{2+16s^2}=\sqrt 2\sqrt{1+8s^2}$ and whose square distance from the center of the ball is at least
$$
\min_t[(s+t-u)^2+(s-t-v)^2]=2(s-\tfrac{u+v}2)^2=2(s-s_0)^2.
$$
Thus, integrating in $t$ first, we have
$$
\int_{s,t:x(s,t)\in B}2\sqrt{1+8s^2}\,dt\,ds\le \int_{s\in\mathbb R}2\sqrt 2\sqrt{[R^2-2(s-s_0)^2]_+}\,ds=\pi R^2
$$
(time = line length/speed; length = $2\sqrt{R^2-\text{(line distance to the center)}^2}$).

The other integral is done in exactly the same way, only you need to integrate with respect to $s$ first. Hence, the area is $<2\pi R^2$, which is equivalent to the requested bound after scaling.

Comment: Thank you! I would like to cite your answer. Would you like to be recognised by just your pseudonym, or real name?

Comment: @AdCh My MO username would be just fine (actually, it is a short version of my real first name as well). And don't forget to thank MO. I believe they can benefit from extra publicity much more than I :-)